# How can I pipe data out from python output in terminal?

Tags: shell, tcsh

I get list of folders using `os.listdir`..

```
python -c "import os; print os.listdir(os.getcwd())"
```

I want to pipe the output to a for loop in shell and iterate in tcsh shell to run a different command to which each folder can be used in iteration.

```
publishContent -dir "each dir name"
```

where each dir name is the output from python above..

I have tried like this before

```
for dirName in `python -c "import os; print os.listdir(os.getcwd())"` do publishConent -dir dirName  End
```

But it didn't seem to work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(t)csh doesn't have a `for` loop, but it does have `foreach`:

```
   foreach name (wordlist)
   ...
   end     Successively sets the variable name to each member of wordlist
           and executes the sequence of commands between this command and
           the matching end.  (Both foreach and end must appear alone on
           separate lines.)  The builtin command continue may be used to
           continue the loop prematurely and the builtin command break to
           terminate it prematurely.  When this command is read from the
           terminal, the loop is read once prompting with `foreach? ' (or
           prompt2) before any statements in the loop are executed.  If
           you make a mistake typing in a loop at the terminal you can rub
           it out.
```

So you want something like:

```
% foreach dirName ( `python -c "import os; print(os.listdir(os.getcwd()))"` )
foreach? echo "$dirName"
foreach? end
```

Which will give:

```
['file',
'file
space',
'file2']
```

There isn't any way to put this on a single line, as far as I know. And the documentation quotes above mention that "Both foreach and end must appear alone on separate lines".

I'm not sure why you're using Python here though:

```
% foreach dirName ( ./* )
foreach? echo "$dirName"
foreach? end
./file
./file space
./file2
```

Which doesn't have the Python syntax, and will handle filenames with spaces correctly.

Both will list all files and directories by the way; use `if ( -d "$dirName" )` to test if it's a directory.

It might be better to use `find` as well:

```
% find . -maxdepth 1 -a -type d -exec publishContent -dir {} \;
```

Comment: thank you martin,  the find solution seemsright way however it returns full path instead of just the folder name from the current working directory !

Comment: or if we cd to cwd then run it is ./file2 when I expected it to be just file2. how can we lstrip like in python here

Comment: I tried using `sed` following an example to get rid of `./` but that didnt worked :
if `setenv var ./file2` then `echo $var:s\./||` it outputs `file2` but similar doesnt work with find: `find . -maxdepth 1 -a -type d -exec publishContent  -dir {}:s\./|| \;`

Comment: You can use `basename` to get just the last part of a path (`basename /home/martin/test` → `test`) @ChangZhao; I think that's what you want? You can put it in backticks in the `find` command: `find [..] -exec publishContent -dir \`basename {}\` \;`. There may also be a `find` flag for it.

Comment: I tried `find * -maxdepth 0 -a  -type d  -exec  mkShotThumbs --seq {} \;` that worked well